# Do I need to do anything other than wire grommets to protect electrical wiring in a 2 1/2 inch steel stud?

Tags: electrical, nec

I'm used to making sure electrical wire is setback 1 1/4 inch from the face of a wood stud, but what are the requirements (US NEC) for 2 1/2 inch steel studs? They appear to come punched out for wires or plumbing, but wouldn't provide enough setback to protect the wiring. The steel stud is designed for a screw to go through it. Are there thicker steel protection plates designed for steels studs, or would that even be necessary?

Comment: Are you using NM Cable?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease, that's right, the plan was standard SIMpull non-metallic jacket wire. Sorry, should have clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NEC language for metal studs is different, it doesn't actually say 1.25", but enforced much the same.

> **300.4(B) Nonmetallic-Sheathed   Cables  and Electrical  Nonmetallic Tubing  Through Metal   Framing
> Members.**
>
> **(1)  Nonmetallic-Sheathed    Cable.** In both    exposed and concealed   locations   where  nonmetallic-sheathed cables  pass    through either  factory-
> or    field-punched,  cut,    or
> drilled   slots   or  holes   in  metal   members,    the cable   shall   be  protected   by  listed  bushings
> or    listed  grommets    covering    all metal   edges   that    are securely    fastened    in  the opening
> prior to  installation    of  the cable.
>
> **(2) Nonmetallic-Sheathed    Cable   and Electrical  Nonmetallic Tubing.**
> Where nails   or screws   are likely  to  penetrate   nonmetallic-sheathed    cable   or  electrical  nonmetallic tubing, a   steel   sleeve, steel   plate,  or  steel   clip    not less    than    1.6 mm  (1∕16   in.)
> in thickness  shall   be  used    to  protect the cable   or  tubing. Exception:
> A listed  and marked  steel   plate   less    than    1.6 mm  (1∕16   in.)    thick   that    provides    equal
> or    better  protection  against nail    or  screw   penetration shall   be  permitted.

Sometimes you can drill an extra 1/4" hole to use a zip-tie to pull the cable against one edge to require just one plate or zip-tie toward concrete wall if stud if stud is just furring.

The wording of the previous paragraph that covers wood leaves no wiggle room to not use nail plates on edges not likely to get nailed or screwed to like double walls or furring.

Comment: Thanks @NoSparksPlease. So is the reason factory punch-outs exist on 2 1/2 steel studs is for armored cable?

Comment: Holes are used for other trades too. I try to stay away from "why", but you seem to be on target since the Articles for AC and MC cables refer to 300.4 (A) for wood and there is no reference to a metal framing paragraph in those Articles. I have seen local jurisdictions adopt local ordinances adding related requirements.

Comment: Are there steel plates specifically designed to protect NM passing through factory openings in metal studs?

Comment: @JimStewart Not aware of steel, plastic protectors work and are less than a quarter a  piece.

Comment: I meant are there plates specifically for metal studs to stop drywall screws from piercing NM like those used on wooden studs to protect wires and plumbing.  Grommets protect NM from sharp edges of holes in the metal studs. Are there steel tubes that fit in these holes in metal studs? Or would plates be pointless since grommets center the wire and drywall screws are short enough to just barely go through the edge of the metal stud?

Comment: They do make plates like a Caddy 304b2 that satisfy 300.4(B)(2). Sometimes the clips don't hold well on the open side of stud so you need to run a framing screw through the small holes, but not always.